# Changing longitude latitude to latitude longitude for coordinate display in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap

How do you change status bar display in arcmap 10.0 from longitude and latitude to latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 1):

There is a useful blog posting on [Converting and Displaying Coordinates in ArcGIS 10](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/01/05/converting-and-displaying-coordinates-in-arcgis-10/) but a notable item missing from that discussion is whether you can reverse the order that Degrees Minutes and Seconds (DMS) values can be displayed at the lower right of ArcMap from longitude-latitude to latitude-longitude.

I think this is because it cannot be done, and I think the reason is to be consistent about coordinates being expressed as XY rather that YX.

Comment: Yes, that's true. ArcMap currently doesn't support axis ordering.